# Read file in zip without unzip(c++)

Tags: c++, zip

I can read file in c++. This is my code:

```
std::string ReadFile(std::string file)
{
    char buff[20480];
    std::ifstream fread(file, std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    fread.read(buff,sizeof(buff));
    std::string str = buff;
    fread.close();
    return str;
}
```

The variable "file" is the FilePath. And I get a folder .zip, I want to read the file in folder. What should I do? I try to use libzip, but it can't solve my problem, maybe I didn't use it by wrong way.

Comment: Yes you are lazy because you did not perform research. -1

Answer (score 1):

No. To unzip a file, you must unzip a file.

You don't need to invoke the `unzip` utility to do it: there are libraries that can expose decompression through a streams API, resulting in code that looks rather similar to what you've written above. But you need to install and learn how to use those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to the API that allows to unpack your file I don't see how directly in the code.
If you are lazy you could write a small script in whatever language you prefer that does the unpacking and then calls your program on the unpacked file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have unzip available. Did you try something like:

```
FILE * file = popen("unzip -p filename", "r");
```

Similarly, `popen("gzip -f filename", "r")` should work for gzip.

In order to parse the output, I'd refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c) (with Windows hints). I don't know about a more C++-style way of doing this.